# SQL query Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I am actually facing a problem that I am unable to find out why is this happening, I've spent many hours but couldn't find any resolution, I would highly appreciate your help.

Well the case is:

I am pulling some COLUMNS from TRACKS table and those are order by two columns TRACKS.SPOTLIGHT and TRACKS.ID

Spotlight column only contains 1 or 0 values
while tracks id's are 1,2,3,4 ... 500 all unique,

and they have a perpage limit of 20 records.

Now when I open up these records pull up correctly in the browser as I wanted 
the first 20 records show absolutely perfect and spotlight that has value 1 are on the top (that's what I wanted).

Now when I load more (next set of 20 records)

It is now repeating the spotlight track again + showing the rest track id's in DESC order.

The problem is I want to prevent the spotlight to repeat on every page loop.

Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong.

Thanks alot guys,

here is my code

```
    function searchTracks($start, $value) {
        // If the $start value is 0, empty the query;
        if($start == 0) {
            $start = '';
        } else {
            // Else, build up the query
            $start = 'AND tracks.id db->real_escape_string($start).'\'';
        }

        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `tracks`, `users` WHERE (`tracks`.`title` 
    LIKE '%s' OR `tracks`.`description` LIKE '%s' OR `tracks`.`tag` LIKE '%s' OR 
    `tracks`.`record` LIKE '%s' ) AND `tracks`.`uid` = `users`.`idu` %s AND 
    `tracks`.`public` = 1 ORDER BY tracks.spotlight DESC, tracks.id DESC LIMIT 
    %s", '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', 
    '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', 
    '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', 
    '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', $start, ($this->per_page + 
    1));

        return $this->getTracks($query, 'searchTracks', '\''.$value.'\'');

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the query output?

Comment: that query is basically unreadable. show what $query is AFTER the sprintf() finishes... and you should really look into using placeholders/prepared statements... But, that being said, it **APPEARS** you have just `LIMIT x`, instead of `LIMIT x,y`. you never provide an offset `y`, so mysql only returns the first `x` rows, exactly as you requested in the query.

Comment: Why shouldn't spotlight repeat if there are more than 20 tracks "spotlighted"?

Comment: We'll if there are 20 tracks spotlighted, then the first 20 that come out should be spotlighted tracks and then the normal query will pull up per page ordered by ID in DESC.

Comment: lets suppose if there are 25 tracks spotlighted, then the first set of 20 results come should be the 20 spotlighed tracks then on the next page (next loop) it should show remaining 5 spotlighted tracks and the remaining 15 tracks ordered by ID in DESC order.
and then on the third page the loop goes in the same manner.  i want that if the SPOTLIGHT column has value 1 then they should come up first, you can say that they are pinned to top.

Comment: @MarcB i have added the "tracks.spotlight DESC, " in ORDER BY just to make the process happen that is in my mind, actuially what i really need is that if the column's SPOTLIGHT has the value 1 then it should be pinned to top (or you can say should be shown at very first)

if i donot include "tracks.spotlight DESC, " and order the tracks just by tracks.ID then everything works fine, the tracks are puling up and on the load more loop of next 20 it shows the other remaining 20 tracks and goes on..

right now only just the "tracks.spotlight DESC, " is repeating the spotlight "1" on every load more

Comment: @MarcB, the offset value is defined on the dedicated page 

list($tracks, $error) = $feed->searchTracks(0, $_GET['q']);
$TMPL['messages'] = $tracks;

Comment: My php is very rusty, but I don't see any "page list($tracks, $error)"; and as @MarcB said, a `LIMIT X` (without two clauses, as opposed to `LIMIT X, Y`, will give you the first X records. You won't have anything else to even "page" through. If you want 20 records at a time, you'd need `LIMIT 0, 20`, `LIMIT 20, 20`, `LIMIT 40, 20`, etc... on successive queries.

Comment: this is what actually happens on the website, it show 20 records, and on click LOAD MORE will show 20 more and goes on...

the problem i am facing is with the ORDER BY columns

i have ordered the query by two columns 
column1 DESC, column2 DESC

now the first 20 shows up correctly with the column1 first then column2

but when i click on load more button to show more 20 records it give me from 20 to 19 from column2 and include a duplicate record from column1 again